# How to post facebook wall with uploaded image/video attachment using koala gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am doing a rails project that involved using Koala gem to call facebook graph API.
Is it possible  to post to facebook wall with picture/video attachment (not picture link) via graph API?

I'm able to to put picture using this command

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
graph.put_picture(params["picture_path"]) #where params["picture_path] is ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object
```

but this only upload to album

I failed doing this:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token)
graph.put_wall_post("hello", {"picture" => params["picture_path"]} ) #where params["picture_path] is ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object
```

Error:

```
 undefined method `local_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000106100a70>
```

Help ?

Answer (score 1):

Here an example with an image generated with rmagick:

First create an image:

```
@clown = Magick::ImageList.new("public/images/framed_clown.jpg")
```

Then put in an album (you must use StringIO) and to_blob:

```
@clown_id = StringIO.open(@clown.to_blob) do |strio|
  response = @graph.put_picture(strio, "image/jpeg")
  response['id']
end
```

Now @clown_id contains the ID of the image, to get the URL:

```
@picture_url = @graph.get_picture(@clown_id)
```

Finally we can post to the wall? Well, remember that you need publish_stream permissions:

```
FACEBOOK_SCOPE = 'user_likes,user_photos,user_photo_video_tags,publish_stream'
```

So we can say:

```
begin 
  @graph.put_wall_post("This a test", {"picture" => @picture_url})
rescue => e
  if(e.fb_error_type == "OAuthException")
    # Already Posted
  end
end
```

Because is better to put a control for duplicated status message....

Enjoy!!!!!

Comment: I get this: `type: OAuthException, code: 100, message: (#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream [HTTP 400]`

Comment: You will also need to add a 'link' key in your post: {"picture" => @picture_url, "link" => @picture_url}.  You can also have the link go to your site as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
graph.put_picture(params["picture_path"], {:message => "Message"})
```

(Taken from: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki/Uploading-Photos-and-Videos)